# Error in relationships between two tables in laravel

Tags: laravel-5.7, table-relationships

I am developing an e-commerce project in which I have the following tables,

**1. Products table** :

- ID (int)
- Title (String)
- **fabric (unsignedInteger)**
- created_at (timestamp)
- I have also used this code below in migration.

```php
$table->foreign('fabric')->references('id')->on('fabrics');
```

**2. Fabric Table**

- ID (int)
- Title (string)

My models are:

```php
    class Product extends Model{
        public function fabric(){
            return $this->hasOne('App\Fabric','id', 'fabric');
        }
    }

    class Fabric extends Model{
            public function products(){
                return $this->belongsTo('App\Product', 'fabric', 'id');
            }
        }
```

I want to get the product **fabric** in view using this

```php
      {{ $product->fabric()->title }}
```

However, it returns

> Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne could
>   not be converted to string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One cannot use the **same name** for the property as well as for function as what I am doing there, I am using **fabric** for both the function as well as for the property.

So I changed my table column from **fabric** to **fabric_id**.

It works!

Answer (score 0):

first of all, I assume that you have defined `$fillable` array within your `fabric` Model with `title`
you should replace

```
  {{ $product->fabric()->title }}
```

by

```
@isset($product->fabric)

       {{ $product->fabric->title }}
@endisset
```

Comment: it shows `Trying to get property 'title' of non-object`.

Comment: because you don't have any fabric related to that product in your database, you should add if test to check if you really have fabric related to that product

Answer (score 0):

You should either replace `{{ $product->fabric()->title }}` with `{{ $product->fabric->title }}`

or

You can replace it with `$product->fabric()->get()->title;`

What you are doing with your original line of code is trying to print out the **relationship** as opposed to the object returned.

Comment: It shows `Trying to get property 'title' of non-object`.

Comment: Hmm try using ```var_dump($product->fabric)``` to see if what you get returned is an array. In that case, it isn't an object and should be accessed with something like ```$product->fabric["title"]```

Comment: Thanks for your time but I got my error, actually I am using the **same name** for a function as well as for a property i.e. **fabric**.